# Read image accurately from url or local

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vbscript, qtp

I want to read the image from url link or local and check if that certain text exist in that image.I am running a `QTP tool` to check all the image links in our website which has certain text since there are lot of image, i can not list all and check one by one. It is really time consuming. So I am looking for some alternatives to do it.

> **step 1**: Read Image from url
>
> **step 2:** check if image has certain text "test"
>
> **step 3:** if it has a text "test" store the link , otherwise dont store
>
> **step 4:** continue process for all image url

I am looking for some solution which provide API so that I can use it in code. It can be any language PHP, JS etc.

I have already tried [i2ocr](http://www.i2ocr.com/) but it is not reading exactly also it does not have API.
I also found this [cloud.ocrsdk.com](http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/Demo/#) but this is also not accurate.

Does anyone know how to do this? Appreciate your help

Comment: Give shot to tesseract-ocr, its command line utility so easy to use with QTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is basic code in QTP which seems to work. I am using  [i2OCR](http://www.i2ocr.com/).

```
systemutil.Run "iexplore.exe", "http://www.i2ocr.com"
'sync the browser
Browser("title:=.*").Sync

Sendkeys("{f5}")

Browser("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").Page("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").WebRadioGroup("i2ocr_options").Select "url" @@ hightlight id_;_Browser("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").Page("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").WebRadioGroup("i2ocr options")_;_script infofile_;_ZIP::ssf19.xml_;_
'imagetest.example.com/files/Image.png
Browser("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").Page("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").WebEdit("i2ocr_url").Set "http://imagetest.example.com/files/Image.png" @@ hightlight id_;_Browser("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").Page("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").WebEdit("i2ocr url")_;_script infofile_;_ZIP::ssf20.xml_;_
Browser("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").Page("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").WebButton("Extract Text").Click @@ hightlight id_;_Browser("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").Page("i2OCR - Free Online OCR").WebButton("Extract Text")_;_script infofile_;_ZIP::ssf21.xml_;_


a = Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").webedit("class:=i2ocr_iTextArea").GetROProperty("innertext")
msgbox a
```

If there is better way or better option, please let me know

Comment: What´s the "@@ hightlight " stuff? Isn´t that ActiveScreen info that is not part of the script code but usually invisible, visible only if you look at QTP´s action script files with a different editor? Does it contribute to the answer?